# Difference between e.target.dataset.value and e.target.value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a difference between e.target.dataset.value and e.target.value? I can't find any information that explains the difference between them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

- The e.target.dataset is read-only property of the
  HTMLOrForeignElement mixin provides   read/write access to custom
  data attributes (data-*) on elements.

```html
<article
  id="electric-cars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">

</article>
```

- The e.target.value is the value property of some input DOM Element.

```html
<input type="number" value="12"/>
```